# Cannot successfully create field 'user' for model 'userdetails': name 'UUID' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models, uuid

I am stuck here. Can't find the solution. I have a class in models.py:

Imports

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount
from geoposition.fields import GeopositionField
from uuid import UUID
import uuid
import hashlib
```

Models:

```
class Pincode(models.Model):
    pincode = models.CharField("PinCode", max_length=6, null=False)
    geom = GeopositionField("Location")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.pincode


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{}'s profile".format(self.user.username)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_profile'

    def profile_image_url(self):
        """
        Return the URL for the user's Facebook icon if the user is logged in via Facebook,
        otherwise return the user's Gravatar URL
        """
        fb_uid = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user_id=self.user.id, provider='facebook')

        if len(fb_uid):
            return "http://graph.facebook.com/{}/picture?width=40&height=40".format(fb_uid[0].uid)

        return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{}?s=40".format(
            hashlib.md5(self.user.email).hexdigest())

    def account_verified(self):
        """
        If the user is logged in and has verified hisser email address, return True,
        otherwise return False
        """
        result = EmailAddress.objects.filter(email=self.user.email)
        if len(result):
            return result[0].verified
        return False


User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])


class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='User_Details',default= uuid.uuid4(),  unique=True)
    pin= models.ForeignKey(Pincode,related_name='pin', null= True, blank=True)
    rating= models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s, %s' % (self.user,  self.pin, self.rating)


class Topmost(models.Model):
     pincode = models.ForeignKey(Pincode, unique=True)
     rating_pincode = models.CharField("Total Rating points", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
     frequency = models.CharField("Number of user", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
     normalized_rank = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
     #objects = models.GeoManager()

     def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s, %s' % (self.pincode,  self.rating_pincode, self.frequency)
```

Cannot migrate it. Shows error:

```
ValueError: Cannot successfully create field 'user' for model 'userdetails': name 'UUID' is not defined.
```

On My Python IDLE:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> a = uuid.uuid4()
>>> type(a)
<class 'uuid.UUID'>
```

It shows the same error when I remove the default field too. 
Any idea?

Comment: did you `import uuid` in the model file?

Comment: @AliNikneshan yes, mainly problem lies in this area

Comment: can you share complete file. seems we missing sth here

Comment: Can take  a look now. Using django-allauth

Answer (score 0):

For creating [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#ref-onetoone) relation you shouldn't set the default value. You have to use it this way:

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='User_Details',  unique=True)
    rating= models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.user)
```

Remove the uuid imports from header (both line) and try again. there is no need of `uuid` in this model.

Comment: it is an auth_user table which is inbuilt in django

Comment: yet you need to import it in this model. did you receive same error? even after deleting `uuid`?

Comment: Yp, I edited the question too. add something in last. You can see that too

Comment: is there any existance database it tries to migrate? you have to find the source of calling uuid!

Comment: its first time migration